# Moving whole Sitecore instance to another location using Sitecore 8.2.7

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-install-framework, iis

When installing Sitecore instance, I chose a wrong physical path but it was meant to be at a different location.
I realized that I get 404 error when I moved whole Sitecore folder (Web and Data, but no data since we are using Azure SQ Server). I changed the physical path for Sitecore instance but it did not work well.

Ay thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change location of your `Web` folder on `IIS` and also update the path to a `Data` folder. It is configured via `dataFolder` variable. You can use patch file to udpate it:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="dataFolder">
      <patch:attribute name="value">/App_Data</patch:attribute>
    </sc.variable>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Can't I just update my Sitecore.config folder instead of making another patch file instead?

Comment: Yes you can update Sitecore.config. However making a patch file is better in the long term. If you don't want to have lots of patch files, you can have just a single one with all your customisations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I will keep that in mind. Upvoted for your kindness:)

Comment: I am afraid I might be missing something, although Sitecore works very fine after moving whole files to another path.

Comment: If you afraid that something still does not work, check the log files for any errors.